# In Excel, How would I attach, or concatenate single attributes together when there are multiple

Tags: excel, excel-formula, attributes, concatenation, excel-tables

I want to attach each attribute to a "name" in a single row.  each row could have one or many attributes.  If there are more than one attributes, I want to create a new line with the 2nd, 3rd, or 4th attributes attached to the names in the first column.
What I am trying to do is take a table that looks like this.

| name | Attr_1 | Attr_2 | Attr_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 101 |  |  |
| Y | 201 | 202 |  |
| Z |  | 302 | 303 |

I want to convert it into a single column that looks like this.

| name |
| --- |
| X101 |
| Y201 |
| Y202 |
| Z302 |
| Z303 |

I am looking to do this with Microsoft Power Automate, or python via Pandas data frame eventually. For now, I just need to figure out if what I am trying to do is possible through Excel.

Currently I am using nested IF statements to concatenate an attribute to the "name" column when the first or second attribute is blank.  However, this leaves out the possibility of a "name" having multiple attributes.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TOCOL and CONCATENATE unless empty then return error:

```
=TOCOL(IF(B2:D4<>"",A2:A4&" - "&B2:D4,NA()),3)
```

[image]

Or Using FILTER:

```
=FILTER(TOCOL(A2:A4&" - "&B2:D4),TOCOL(B2:D4)<>"")
```

Answer (score 0):

With Power Query:

Right click on "name" column, Unpivot other columns

Remove "Attribute" column

Merge "name" and "Value" columns

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]